# What class is the iMessage keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to access the class just for the keyboard which has the chatbox in MFMessageComposeViewController?

I have already tried different pods to simulate the same but I think the best look is still the native messaging keyboard chatbox.

Here is the screenshot of the keyboard I want to use in my scenario.

[image: iMessage keyboard]

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Apple developed their own UI and UX for iMessage.

However you could implement this by yourself. Some useful content on this:

[Check out this GitHub repository for a similar experience. (Customization needed)](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)

[Or find other useful repository for your use-case.](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#messaging)